Movie where friends travel to Las Vegas and go to Mike Tyson's home?
I'm looking for a movie with the following description: 
There are three friends and one is in a relationship among the three of them. I don't know what their relation is. They are going to a Las Vegas Casino in one of the friends father's car. They reach Las Vegas and during the night they were fully drunk. All four go to Mike Tyson's home. They take his Tiger with them and put it in the casino hotel Room. The Next morning one of the friends has a wedding and one friend was not found.

Er...The Hangover?

@steelersquirrel So fast and clean answer.Thanks that's it I am looking for.

Well, it's a pretty popular movie...the Mike Tyson clue gave it away ;)

@steelersquirrel Yeah I remember that seen that's why I am giving this clue.

A google search with the string "las vegas tiger mike tyson movie" would have been much easier.

@Nitish Thanks that's Great.

The movie that you are referring to is The Hangover from 2009.
Four friends head to Las Vegas for a bachelor party.  They do indeed drink too much and wake up the following morning not remembering what they did.  One of the friends was indeed lost and Mike Tyson's tiger was in their hotel room:

To celebrate his upcoming marriage to Tracy Garner, Doug Billings
  travels to Las Vegas with his best friends Phil Wenneck, Stuart "Stu"
  Price, and Tracy's brother Alan, in Doug's future father-in-law's
  vintage Mercedes-Benz W111. They spend the night at Caesars Palace,
  where they relax in their hotel suite before celebrating with a few
  drinks on the hotel rooftop. The next morning, Phil, Stu, and Alan
  awaken to find they have no memory of the previous night, and Doug is
  nowhere to be found. Stu's tooth is in Alan's pocket, their suite is
  in a state of complete disarray, a tiger is in their bathroom, a
  chicken in their living room, and a baby is in the closet, whom they
  name "Carlos". They find Doug's mattress impaled on a statue outside
  of Caesars Palace and when they ask for their Mercedes, the valet
  delivers an LVPD police cruiser.
  > Returning to their suite, they find the boxer Mike Tyson, who orders
  the trio to return the tiger to his mansion immediately.


The Hangover
For a bachelor party, three best men and the groom take a road trip to Las Vegas. They wake up the next morning to realise that not only have they lost the groom but also have no recollection.
